# Filtrar elementos de mysql con un botón

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una tienda online la cual tiene algunos filtros por categorias ejemplos niñios/niñas. La idea es activarlos con un enlace a href.

En el html general tengo todos los productos que voy mostrando de uno a uno los datos estan almacenados en un array que traje de mysql y por cada fila tiene un articulo, en las columnas hay distintos datos como la categoria si es de niño o niña por ejemplo. Este array se va mostrando con un while.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click en e enlace href, en vez de mostrar todos los articulos, se vean solo los que cumplen la condicion elegida por ejemplo los de niño, esto lo hago con otro while que recorre el arreglo antes dicho y va formando otro arreglo a medida que los articulos cumplen la condicion.

Ahora bien como hago para que ese codigo php que redimisiona el arreglo se ejecute al hacer click en el enlace de la categoria de niño, por ejemplo.

Adjunto parte del codigo php,

Desde ya muchas gracias,

```
introducir el código aquí<section class="products-list">
            <?php 
            $i=0;
            while ($i<$c) {
                echo '<div class="product-item">';
                    echo '<img class="img_art" src="' . $array_art[$i][2] . '">';
                         if ($array_art[$i][3]<>0){
                            echo '<div class="img_detalles">';
                            echo '<img src="' . $array_art[$i][4] . '">';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        echo '<div class="more">';
                            echo '<p> Ver colores y talles </p>';
                         echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="art">';
                        echo '<a class="articulo" href="#' . $array_art[$i][0] . '" data-toggle="modal" >';
                            echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][0] .  "</br></span>";
                            echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][1] .  "</br></span>";
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </section>
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema concreto? Revisa [ask]

Comment: Agrege info en la pregunta pricipal

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta. Se agradece un párrafo donde expliques sencillamente lo que quieres hacer y cómo tienes organizadas las cosas: *quiero hacer esto, tengo esta base de datos, tengo este archivo que muestra esto con estos componentes y quiero hacer esto otro al presionar este botón*. Muchas veces las cosas se complican porque el programador ha implementando una lógica confusa para resolver su problema, habiendo maneras más fáciles de hacerlo. Dinos a dónde quieres llegar, no por dónde quieres llegar y quizá te ayudaremos mejor.